# django-uni-form helpers and CSRF tags over POST

Tags: python, django, uniform

I'm using django-uni-forms to display my fields, with a rather rudimentary example straight out of their book.

When I render the form fields using `<form>{%csrf_tag%} {%form|as_uni_form%}</form>`, everything works as expected.

However, django-uni-form Helpers allow you to generate the form tag (and other helper-related content) using the following syntax -- `{% with form.helper as helper %}{% uni_form form helper%}{%endwith%}` -- This creates the `<form>` tag for me, so there's nowhere to embed my own CSRF_token. When I try to use this syntax, the form renders perfectly, but without a CSRF token, and so submitting the form fails every time.

Does anyone have experience with this? Is there an established way to add the token? I much prefer the second syntax, for re-use reasons.
Thanks!

Comment: According to this template the csrf tag should be present https://github.com/pydanny/django-uni-form/blob/master/uni_form/templates/uni_form/whole_uni_form.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the source? It should already be there. The uni_form template tag should include it automatically.

Comment: Turns out my requirements.txt (pip manifest) had 0.7.0 hardcoded, and I hadn't noticed (Pinax defined that for me). Updating to the trunk fixed for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem with django-uni-form. The csrf token does not show up after the `<form>` tag if I use:

```
{% load uni_form_tags %}
{% uni_form form helper %}
```

or:

```
{% load uni_form_tags %}
{% with form.helper as helper %}
    {% uni_form form helper%}
{%endwith%}
```

If I include it manually it works:

```
<form action='{{ request.path }}' method='POST' class="uniForm">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|safe }}
</form>
```

I found a [blog post](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2011/01/20/djangouniform-csrf/) that outlines how to include the csrf token manually:

```
helper = FormHelper()

csrf_token = Hidden(
                name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
                value = request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'])
helper.add_input(csrf_token)
```

Not at all pretty but at least it gets the uni-form to work.

Comment: Check out my comment on the above response; I marked him as correct because, well, technically he was :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to install django-uni-form from GitHub until the version on PyPi is updated to 0.8.

```
pip install https://github.com/pydanny/django-uni-form/tarball/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the most recent version of django-uni-form. It fixes this and so much more.